# Send list of custom class objects with alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is my class model

```
class OrderModel {

    var mId:String?
    var productCode:String?
    var orderQty : Int?
    var  productRate : Int?
    var requiredOn : String?
    var orderAddress:String?
    var remarks:String?

    var productTtitle : String?
    var orderAmount:Int?
    var branchId:String?

    }
```

and i want to send JSON like

```
{
   "order_model":[
    {
           "m_id": "121212",
           "Product_code": "000001",
           "Order_qty": 2,
           "Product_rate": 100,
           "Order_amount" : 200,
           "Required_on": "2018-02-01T12:32:33.8550337+05:00",
           "branch_id" : "1701001",
           "Order_Address": "address",
           "Remarks": "rem"
       }, {
       "m_id": "12234334",
       "Product_code": "000002",
       "Order_qty": 1,
       "Product_rate": 100,
       "Order_amount" : 100,
       "Required_on": "2018-02-01T12:32:33.8550337+05:00",
       "branch_id" : "1701001",
       "Order_Address": "address",
       "Remarks": "rem"
   }
 ]
}
```

There are a lot of methods on this topic but i got nothing for my issue and tried all of them.I am not getting the solution on how to convert the list of MyCalss Model to specified JSON

This is my code

```
var prams: [String: Any] = [:]
    var prodArray:[NSMutableDictionary] = [NSMutableDictionary()]


    for product in OrderSingleton.sharedInstance.orderModelList
    {
        let prod: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        prod.setValue(product.mId, forKey: "m_id")
        prod.setValue(product.productCode, forKey: "Product_code")
        prod.setValue(product.orderQty, forKey: "Order_qty")
        prod.setValue(product.productRate, forKey: "Product_rate")
        prod.setValue(product.orderAmount, forKey: "Order_amount")
        prod.setValue(product.requiredOn, forKey: "Required_on")
        prod.setValue(product.branchId, forKey: "branch_id")
        prod.setValue(product.orderAddress, forKey: "Order_Address")
        prod.setValue(product.remarks, forKey: "Remarks")
        prodArray.append(prod)
    }
    prams["order_model"] = prodArray
    var request = URLRequest(url: try! urlString.asURL())
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let values = prams
    print(values)

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)
    Alamofire.request(request).responseData { response in

        switch (response.result) {
        case .success:
              let json = response.result.value
              let jsonString = String(data: json!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
              print("JSON String " , jsonString!)
        case .failure(let error):
              print ("error ",error)
        }
    }
```

and my output for the above code is

```
["order_model": [{
    "Order_Address" = 923218565452;
    "Order_amount" = 1;
    "Order_qty" = 1;
    "Product_code" = 000001;
    "Product_rate" = 1500;
    Remarks = rem;
    "Required_on" = "2018-02-01T12:32:33.8550337+05:00";
    "branch_id" = 1701001;
    "m_id" = 923218565452;
}, {
    "Order_Address" = 923218565452;
    "Order_amount" = 1;
    "Order_qty" = 1;
    "Product_code" = 000002;
    "Product_rate" = 1500;
    Remarks = rem;
    "Required_on" = "2018-02-01T12:32:33.8550337+05:00";
    "branch_id" = 1701001;
    "m_id" = 923218565452;
}]]
```

this is the code i tried

Comment: Do you understand that the JSON you want is nothing more than Dictionary, Array, String and Numbers? If yes, try to reproduce it with Swift Dictionary, Swift Array, String and Numbers.

Comment: "tried all of them" - you should post the code of your attempts, the results, and the errors you recieved, rather than simply saying nothing worked and hoping someone will do it for you

Comment: I have added my code please look again thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write your alamofire request like this. 
It will help. 
Happy Coding :)

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: prams,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseData{ response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:

            break
        case .failure( let error):
            print(error)

            break
        }
    }
}
```